# Cant use standard facebook OpenGraph Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

as the title says facebook does not allow me to use a standard OpenGraph Action. in this case Watch i would like my users to be able to watch a movie in my app.

this is the output i get for: /me/{NameSpace}:watch with a post movie = http://www.example.com/api/opengraph/Movie.php the movie contains the following:

```
    <html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="223293494357017" />
    <meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" />
    <meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.example.com/api/opengraph/Movie.php" />
    <meta property="og:title"       content="Sample Movie" />
    <meta property="og:image"       content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />


</head>
<body>
Sample Movie
</body>
</html>
```

the output i get from facebook when trying this in the OpenGraph API Explorer

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /{NAMESPACE}:watch", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

This is weird because when i try this with a custom action (bekijk [dutch translation for watch]) it does work and actually posts on my facebook wall.

Do you guys have any idea what i am doing wrong.

Ofcourse i have checked the namespace multiple times Sandbox mode = on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution:

for official watch action i need to use this url:

me/video.watches